# How to assign values from a data reader including null values in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datatable, datareader

I have 12 textboxes of subject names. And i want to retrieve the data from an sql query passing through a data reader.

SQL QUERY:

```
sql = "SELECT subject,QuarterlyG
       FROM ass_all
       WHERE studID = @STUDID AND SchoolYear =@SYEAR and GQuarter = @QUARTER ORDER BY subject"
       ConnDB()
       sqlCommand()

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDID", LVStudList.FocusedItem.Text)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SYEAR", GlobalSchYear)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUARTER", resultQuarter)
       dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Now, in the instance if the subject in the database is lesser than 12 including its corresponding grades. How can i put "0" in each of the text boxes in their corresponding subject names, since the query result will vary only on what subject has already been encoded in the database. And how can i put the exact value for each subjects in their corresponding textboxes.

[image: This is my database]

[image: list of Subjects]
[image: Form textbox]

Comment: What is the return type of that `IsDBNull` method? Does it make sense to compare a value of that type to a literal `String`?

Comment: It compares a string data type which is the name of the subject, then get the value in the second column which is the grade

Comment: To answer @jmcilhinney 's question look at the MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1  `IsDBNull` is a Function. Functions have a return type, right? Check the docs and see what the return type of this funtion is. Hint: It does NOT compare a string data type.

Comment: I think it is boolean

Comment: That is correct. So, now you understand why `If dr.IsDBNull(0) = "Filipino" Then` doesn't work. How could a Boolean be equal to "Filipino"?

Comment: That is why i am having this question because I know that code does not work, and i am looking for someone to help me figure out how to get those data from the database and put them in the textboxes. Thanks